# CouchDB reduce function gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript, couchdb, mapreduce, couchapp

I am developing a couchapp. I have documents that contains a field called tags, and I am trying to retrieve the unique tags among all the docs. My map/reduce function is as follows:

map.js

```
function(doc){
        if(doc.tags){
            emit(doc.tags,1);
        }
}
```

reduce.js

```
function(keys,values,rereduce){
    return sum(values);
}
```

And the output returned is the count of all the tags. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: 0 accepted answers....good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of all tags you don't need a reduce function. You need to call your view with the 
option `group=true`. So for example you call

```
http://localhost:5984/yourdb/views/tag_view?group=true
```

or with [couch.js](http://daleharvey.github.com/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/%24.couch.html) you can do

```
$.couch.db.view('your_view', {data: {"group": true}});
```

If you look at the documentation you see that you define `ajaxOptions` for the request in the same way you define them for normal ajax request in jQuery. So you just use the data option documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

For further information see [CouchDB Wiki Grouping](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Grouping).

Comment: I am using the jquery.couch.js plugin. So how do I call this in it: I tried $.couch.db($db).view("app/my_view?group=true") but dint work.